# How to get all the objects which access a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in database and there're lots of SPs or functions or views use data inside this table.  Now I'd like to find out all the objects in DB which access this table, including entire hierarchy.  For example, stored procedure A invokes this table and stored procedure B invokes A, I'd like to list both A and B.

I use a tool named "SQL Search" or sql script to find 1st hierarchy which access the table directly but is there any way to find other hierarchy easily?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677168%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: You don't *invoke a table* - you select from it, insert into it .... ("invoke" means "execute" as in code, script etc. - nothing like that happening here)

Comment: Dean, I need a sql to list all the objects as a tree structure.  The root is the table.  I don't want to check them one by one by hand.

Comment: Apologize for my bad English...should I say "call the table"?

Comment: You never bothered to read through the article I linked to, did you? There are samples in it to do exactly what you need, using recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0):

try this query... it will list all procedures, function, views, triggers... whose definition contains required characters set in this case table

```
SELECT db, o.name,m.definition  
FROM urdbname.sys.sql_modules m  
INNER JOIN dbnamee..sysobjects o ON m.object_id=o.id WHERE [definition] like '%table%'
```

Comment: I don't think this query meets the requirement.  It only list 1st level objects.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name,
referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.yourtablename', 'OBJECT');
```